# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vungle.warren.Vungle.updateConsentStatus after updating to latest Vungle SDK

Tags: mopub, vungle-ads

I am using Vungle ad network via MoPub SDK for showing ads in Android Application. I have just updated the Vungle SDK to latest as per their changelog (version 6.3.12). Now the app is crashing. The exception is as below:

```
08-03 16:56:58.480 14071-14071/com.globaldelight.vizmato E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.globaldelight.vizmato, PID: 14071
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vungle.warren.Vungle.updateConsentStatus
        at com.mopub.mobileads.VungleRouter$2.onSuccess(VungleRouter.java:85)
        at com.vungle.warren.Vungle$2.onResponse(Vungle.java:479)
        at com.vungle.warren.network.VungleApiClient$4.onResponse(VungleApiClient.java:514)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could someone please help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.